# Kunena And Jomsocial Integration

Tags: joomla

We are using Kunena and Jomsocial and everything works great.
Is it possible to stop the changes in the forum from showing in Jomsocial's recent activity list as we have some private forums and do not want the changes in the forum to appear to the general users in Jomsocial.

We are using Kunena 1.6.1

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for an older version but might still apply to 1.6.x:

http://www.kunena.org/forum/11-jomsocial/63170-enable-jomsocial-user-points-disable-activity-stream